# Display custom_background outside wp_head()

Tags: themes, theme-customizer, wp-head, custom-background

My theme is a very small one page theme which really doesn't need all the scripts, so I've created a few options to remove `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` so the user can choose if they want to enable or disable those.

However, my site does use the `custom_background()` feature which is placed in the `wp_head()` so when they disable `wp_head()`, they will also remove the background.

Is there a way to place the `custom_background()` code outside the `wp_head()`?

Comment: Many themes/plugins work on footer and header how you will maintain the compatibility of your theme with WP and plugins ?

Comment: @Sumit Well, it's a choice for the user. If they don't want to use plugins and want a faster site, they can remove the `wp_head()` function. If they do want to use plugins and all that, they can keep `wp_head()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`custom_background()` places the CSS to `wp_head()` as you mentioned so to get those CSS as if you don't have `wp_head()` in your header, these tweaks from the core files would help:

```
function wpse_228588_background_image_css() {
    $background_styles = '';
    if ( $bgcolor = get_background_color() )
        $background_styles .= 'background-color: #' . $bgcolor . ';';

    $background_image_thumb = get_background_image();
    if ( $background_image_thumb ) {
        $background_image_thumb = esc_url( set_url_scheme( get_theme_mod( 'background_image_thumb', str_replace( '%', '%%', $background_image_thumb ) ) ) );

        // Background-image URL must be single quote, see below.
        $background_styles .= ' background-image: url(\'' . $background_image_thumb . '\');'
            . ' background-repeat: ' . get_theme_mod( 'background_repeat', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-repeat' ) ) . ';'
            . ' background-position: top ' . get_theme_mod( 'background_position_x', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-position-x' ) );
    }
    return $background_styles; // CSS
}
```

Usage:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">body{<?php echo wpse_228588_background_image_css(); ?>}</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. You can access the custom background image directly with [`get_background_image()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_background_image), like this:

```
echo '<style>body.custom-background {background-image: url(' . get_background_image() . ');} </style>';
```